# How to store a byte array into a SQL Server varbinary(MAX) field in Java?

Tags: java, android, sql-server, varbinary

I have an Android application that receives an image as byte array and I want to save it on my SQL Server database on a varbinary(MAX) field.

I'm using jtds and tried to run:

```
Statement statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(
   "INSERT INTO TB_IMAGE (ID, IMAGE) VALUES (" + image.getId() + "," + image.getImage() + ")")
```

I'm able to execute the query but it throws the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid SQL statement or JDBC escape, terminating ']' not found.
```

Then I tried:

```
String query = ("INSERT INTO TB_IMAGE (ID, IMAGE) VALUES (" + image.getId() + ", ?)");
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(query);
preparedStatement.setBinaryStream(1, image.getImage());
```

But this requires a java.io.InputStream and the code does not compile.

For reference, this is my Image class:

```
public class Image {
    private int Id;
    private byte[] Image;

    public Image (int id) { this.Id = id; }

    public int getId() { return Id; }
    public void setId(int id) { Id = id; }

    public byte[] getImage() { return Image; }
    public void setImage(byte[] image) { Image = image; }
}
```

How can I save the image, a byte[], inside a varbinary(MAX) field?

Answer (score 0):

Convert the byte array to a hex string, and provide the unquoted hex string in the SQL. Like this:

```
insert into tb_image(id, image) values(100, 0xaabbccdd11223344)
```

Comment: This approach lead me to another error: The identifier that starts with '....' is too long. Maximum length is 128. Any idea on how to solve it?

Comment: Does the client library support parameters? Pretty sure 128 is not a limit for parameter value length.